# How to send value retrieved from AJAX response to another file?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am retrieving some values from AJAX response and redirecting to another page and I want to send those values to that page.

This is my AJAX code

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/oauth.php',
    type: 'post',
    data:{
        email:email,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        async: false
    },
    success: function(response) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(response);
        if(data!=''){
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                alert(data[i].uid);    // Here I am getting correct value                 
                window.location.href = "https://localhost/gaming/registration.php"; //Now when response is ok I'm redirecting to this. I want to send the above value to this page
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [query string parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/oauth.php',
    type: 'post',
    data:{
        email:email,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        async: false
    },
    success: function(response) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(response);
        if(data!=''){
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                alert(data[i].uid);    // Here I am getting correct value                 
                window.location.href = "https://localhost/gaming/registration.php?uid=" + data[i].uid; // This will add ?uid=<your_value> to the URL
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Then in your PHP `registration.php` you can simply retrive this value using `$_GET['uid']`

Answer (score 0):

you can use $_SESSION, in the call toi the 'php/oauth.phphere':

```
 <?php 
 //Start the session
   session_start();
   ?>

     you code to retrieve the data from database.    

  <?php
  // Set session variables
  $_SESSION["uid"] = "some value";
  ?>
```

in the https://localhost/gaming/registration.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
// Echo session variables that were set on previous page
 $uid =$_SESSION["uid"]
 ?>

</body>
</html>
```